# Authorization token sent from frontend doesn't works (JWT)

Tags: angular, spring-security, jwt, authorization

Login/register process is working, but I can't access to endpoint with @secured or @preauthorize annotation.

LOGS IN CONSOLE (spring app): "Unauthorized error: Full authentication is required to access this resource".

With POSTMAN it works fine, **so it's problem with frontend.**

Angular:

**_helper**

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

import { TokenStorageService } from '../_services/token-storage.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const TOKEN_HEADER_KEY = 'Authorization';       // for Spring Boot back-end

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private token: TokenStorageService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let authReq = req;
    const token = this.token.getToken();
    if (token != null) {
      authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });
    }
    return next.handle(authReq);
  }
}

export const authInterceptorProviders = [
  { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthInterceptor, multi: true }
];
```

**_services**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

const TOKEN_KEY = 'auth-token';
const USER_KEY = 'auth-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenStorageService {

  constructor() { }

  signOut(): void {
    window.sessionStorage.clear();
  }

  public saveToken(token: string): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY, token);
  }

  public getToken(): string | null {
    return window.sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)
  }

  public saveUser(user: any): void {
    window.sessionStorage.removeItem(USER_KEY);
    window.sessionStorage.setItem(USER_KEY, JSON.stringify(user));
  }

  public getUser(): any {
    const user = window.sessionStorage.getItem(USER_KEY);
    if (user) {
      return JSON.parse(user);
    }

    return {};
  }

}
```

**example of component (for user)**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { TokenStorageService } from '../_services/token-storage.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form: any = {
    username: null,
    password: null
  };
  isLoggedIn = false;
  isLoginFailed = false;
  errorMessage = '';
  roles: string[] = [];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private tokenStorage: TokenStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.tokenStorage.getToken()) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    const { username, password } = this.form;

    this.authService.login(username, password).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenStorage.saveToken(data.token); //token
        this.tokenStorage.saveUser(data);

        this.isLoginFailed = false;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
        this.roles = this.tokenStorage.getUser().roles;
        this.reloadPage();
      },
      err => {
        this.errorMessage = err.error.message;
        this.isLoginFailed = true;
      }
    );
  }

  reloadPage(): void {
    window.location.reload();
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After running spring application in debugger I got this:
((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)authentication).authorities = Cannot find local variable 'authentication'

there is **AuthJwt** code from spring boot app:

```
@Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        logger.error("Unauthorized error: {}", authException.getMessage());
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Error: Unauthorized");
    }
```

Comment: `const token = this.token.getToken();
 debugger;
 if (token != null) {
     authReq = req.clone({ headers: req.headers.set(TOKEN_HEADER_KEY, 'Bearer ' + token) });}`

Put a debugger tag there and check what's inside the request cloned and modified by the interceptor

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't catch this point as if it never happened

Comment: Did you add `AuthInterceptor` as a provider on `AppModule`?

Maybe add your `AppModule` to the question. I think one also needs to import the `HttpClientModule` and `BrowserModule` to `@NgModule`

Comment: So... I did forget, thank you a lot !
Now it works :)

Comment: Do you mind me adding that as an answer and you accepting it to help future users?

Comment: Sure, no problem ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `AuthInterceptor` is also declared in `AppModule` as a provider.

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [authInterceptorProviders],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```